# Sending a HttpRequest back down a HttpRequest (proxy)

Tags: vb.net, stream, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I have the following code:

```
With context.Response
     Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.Google.com/")
     req.Proxy = Nothing
     Dim res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
     Dim Stream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream
     .OutputStream.Write(Stream, 0, Stream.Length)
End With
```

Sadly, the above code doesn't work.  I need to take the RequestStream and put it into the OutputStream from the context.Response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error message or does it not compile?

Comment: It doesn't compile/error message.  It's not supposed to.  OutputStream.Write expects a byte array.  What can I do to allow me to write a stream to OutputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write takes a byte array, whereas you are passing it a stream.

Try reading from the stream and getting all the data before writing it back.

First, read the data into an intermediate byte array ([Taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx)):

```
Dim bytes(Stream.Length) As Byte
Dim numBytesToRead As Integer = s.Length
Dim numBytesRead As Integer = 0
Dim n As Integer
While numBytesToRead > 0
    ' Read may return anything from 0 to 10.
    n = Stream.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, 10)
    ' The end of the file is reached.
    If n = 0 Then
        Exit While
    End If
    numBytesRead += n
    numBytesToRead -= n
End While
Stream.Close()
```

Then write it to the output stream:

```
.OutputStream.Write(bytes,  0, Stream.Length)
```